# How to detect the re-reduce stage in MongoDB map/reduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I use the following map/reduce setup to collect some data into array:

```
map: function() { emit(this.key, [this.item]); },
reduce: function(key, values) {
                     var items = [];
                     values.forEach( function(value) {items.concat(value.item);} );
                     return items;
         },
out: {reduce: "result_collection"}
```

I want to improve the code and detect if the resulting collection has been changed during the re-reduce stage (when mongo invokes reduce with the current content of the "result_collection").

In other words, how to know that any documents have been emitted by the Map contain "item" that does not exist in the "result_collection" yet (under the same key, of course)?

This information can help at some further processing stages e.g. query "result_collection" to get the documents that have been updated during the map/reduce stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do this, use a `finalize` function to adjust the `value` after all reduction is finished. You'll have to add more logic to the reduce function to handle the modified output.

I'll show you an example with the simple map-reduce defined by the following `map` and `reduce` functions:

```
var map = function() { emit(this.k, this.v) }
var reduce = function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values) }
```

On documents that look like `{ "k" : 0, "v" : 1 }`, the map-reduce defined by the above functions produces result documents that look like `{ "_id" : 0, "value" : 17 }`. Define a `finalize` function to modify the final document:

```
var finalize = function (key, reducedValue) { return { "m" : true, "v" : reducedValue } }
```

Now modify `reduce` to handle an element of `values` that might be an object of the above form:

```
var reduce2 = function(key, values) { 
    var sum = 0; 
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
        if (typeof values[i] == "object") { sum += values[i].v }
        else { sum += values[i] } 
    }

    return sum 
}
```

Output looks like

```
{ "_id" : 0, "value" : { "m" : true, "v" : 14 } }
{ "_id" : 1, "value" : { "m" : true, "v" : 34 } }
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : { "m" : true, "v" : 8 } }
```

so you can tell what's been modified by `value.m`. Your further processing can set `v.m` to `false` so you'll see what hasn't been processed yet after each map-reduce.

Comment: This scheme violates the map/reduce requirements, doesn't it? The return values of map, reduce, and finalize must be of the same type.

Comment: Which map/reduce requirements? MongoDB isn't enforcing any such requirements. The idea is valid and the example code works. I do agree this isn't a fantastic thing to do, but I also believe the use case is worthy, so I prefaced my answer with "if you must do this" :D.

Comment: The requirements are [in the doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#db.collection.mapReduce) and [more explanation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-reduce-function/). I agree that your code works, but will it work in more complicated use cases?

Comment: Glancing over the requirements, I think my example fulfills all of them. The `finalize` function does not have to return the same type as anything else. Is there one you can point out that is violated? I also would call what I've shown you a strategy, exemplified by my code. The idea of the strategy is sound. You have to write the code to implement it for your case, which may be more complicated than the example, and may not be worth maintaining compared to simply processing the entire output collection, changed and unchanged docs alike.

Comment: Indeed, I erroneously assigned extra requirements to the finalize function. Apparently, its return type may not be identical to the map and reduce outputs. This is what confused me _"... apply the reduce function to both the new and the existing documents and overwrite the existing document with the result"_